# how i can send data to html cefsharp vb.net

Tags: cefsharp

This is the source code for the webpage I'm working on.

And This is my code to send the data from the textbox to the web page browser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('input[ng-model=NationalId]').value='" + TextBox1.Text + "'") browser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('input[ng-model=PrincipleCode]').value='" + TextBox2.Text + "'")

it works and sends the data, but when I press the enter button, it does not feel the written data and asks me to enter the data
plz help me

Comment: <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control number" maxlength="16" ng-model="NationalId">

<input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control number" maxlength="16" ng-model="PrincipleCode">

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for web pages to have additional input validation.

I've recently published a CefSharp specific port of puppeteer Sharp which should let you do something like the following:

```cs
var page = await chromiumWebBrowser.GetPuppeteerPageAsync();
          
// Type into input field
await page.TypeAsync(@"input[ng-model=NationalId]", TextBox1.Text);
```

The package is available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Puppeteer/
See also https://github.com/cefsharp/Puppeteer/blob/main/samples/searching/Program.cs

Comment: i cant understand how i can use this code and my code by vb.net
plz help me

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a VB.net example for you. The first await using simply means call async dispose. You can skip that and manually call Dispose or the the VB.net equivalent of a using statement.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with await then check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/