# Autofill by Selector not working on all Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Normally, i Login to formbased login pages by executing the following:

```
cefsharp_browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.querySelector('#input-email').value='myemail@test.com';");
cefsharp_browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.querySelector('#input-password').value='mysupersecretpassword';");
```

But now i´m actually struggeling to login to a Page(https://lagerimgriff.app/login) on which the code above doesn´t work.

The Form is beeing filled with the Values shown above but injecting the Values that way or by ID, the Login-Form doesn´t realize any input, saying the field beeing empty.

I´m not a WebDev but it seems to me that there is some intermediate JS which is checking the Fields for validity(f.e. the mail must contain @ followed by a . ), maybe that is the Problem?

As this seems to be JS related i´ll tag it too.

Is there any way of archieving an automated login on that Page?

Comment: It's not uncommon for web pages to have additional validation, check for key strokes etc. I have recently released a CefSharp specific puppeteer implementation that can be used for automation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70377644/4583726

Comment: @amaitland Thank you very much, that did the Job. Can i use the Puppeteer only in an 64bit environment?

Comment: The CefSharp port should work with x86, x64 and arm64.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/Puppeteer#cefsharp-puppeteer has a little more information.